# How to make python search and print the first line also

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to read and print all lines that start with 'VISIT' but the below code keep ignoring the first line, I searched a bit and understood that by the time it starts the search it is at the second line, I tried adding `f.seek(0)` but it didn't work.

```
   with open("visit_log.txt") as f:

        lines = f.readlines()

        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if line.startswith('VISIT'):
                for l in lines[i]: print l,
                print
```

My text file:

```
VISIT 82.81.123.011 Israel
VISIT 82.81.123.001 Israel
VISIT 82.81.123.002 Israel
VISIT 82.81.123.003 Israel
VISIT 82.81.123.004 Israel
AVISIT 82.81.123.456 Israel
bVISIT 82.81.123.456 Israel
cVISIT 82.81.123.456 Israel
LLLLL 888.888.888.888 Israel
VISIT 55 82.81.123.005 Israel
________________
VISIT 82.81.123.006 Israel
```

Comment: `for l in lines[i]: print l,` can be replaced with `print line`, Can you attach top 10 lines of your log file ?

Comment: Your code works for me when I tested it on the text you provided.

Comment: Check if there are any spaces or hidden characters at the beginning of the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue,
I was focused the first line in the text document,
When I printed the file without the if statement I found at the beginning of the line:

```
∩╗┐
```

Even deleting all the file haven't helped.

Found the reason.

https://superuser.com/questions/601282/%CC%81-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Answer (score 2):

Do we really need `readlines()` at all?

```
with open("visit_log.txt") as f:
    for line in f:   
        if line.startswith('VISIT'):
            print line
```

Comment: Thanks, Have implemented.